# Bagging throws "subscript out of bounds" error

Tags: r, r-caret

I am trying to create a classification model that predicts the variable 'sex' in my dataset. When I try to run the line "abalone.bagging <- bagging(formula = M~., data = abalone.train)", it throws this error:

> Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, , i, value = matrix(as.numeric(pred == levels(vardep)[i]),  :
> subscript out of bounds

My code reads as follows:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(e1071)
library(caret)
library(rpart)
library(ipred)
library(tree)

abalone <- read.csv("abalone.csv")

set.seed(898)

TrainIDs <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), nrow(abalone), replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.7,0.3))

abalone.train <- abalone[TrainIDs,]
abalone.test <-  abalone[-TrainIDs,]

abalone.bagging <- bagging(formula = M~., data = abalone.train)
```

I'm not too familiar with the bagging function, and there doesn't appear to be many good sources for learning about it online. I have tried adding different arguments like `coob=TRUE` and different `nbagg` values but they don't change anything.